# Flutter Firebase Storage not woriking: no default bucket

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload a `pdf-file` to `Firebase-Storage` using this function:

```
  static Future<String> savePdf({
    required Uint8List assetAsUint8List,
    required String fileName,
    required DocumentType documentType,
  }) async {
    String path =
        '${BackendService().keys.studs}/${AuthenticationService().currentUser?.uid}/${documentType.name}/$fileName';

    await FirebaseStorage.instanceFor().ref(path).putData(
          assetAsUint8List,
        );
    return FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(path).getDownloadURL();
  }
```

but this fails with this `error`:

> Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/no-bucket] No default storage bucket could be found. Ensure you have correctly followed the Getting Started guide.

I `configure` my app like this inside my `main`:

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: kIsWeb || Platform.isAndroid
        ? FirebaseOptions(
            apiKey: "my-api-key",
            appId: "my-app-id",
            messagingSenderId: "my-messaing-sender-id",
            projectId: "appflug",
          )
        : null,
  );
  runApp(
    const App(),
  );
}
```

**It is actually working on iOS! But NOT on Android or Web...**

I followed the documentation but it is simply not working... I coulnd't find anything helpful on this!

What am I missing here?

Let me know if you need any more info!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution was rather simple: I needed to add the `storageBucket` in my `FirebaseOptions` so my `main` looks like this:

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: kIsWeb || Platform.isAndroid
        ? FirebaseOptions(
            apiKey: "my-app-key",
            appId: "my-app-id",
            messagingSenderId: "my-messaging-sender-id",
            projectId: "my-project-id",
            storageBucket: "myapp.appspot.com",
          )
        : null,
  );
  runApp(
    const App(),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you working on android then The solution was simple: I needed to add the storageBucket from google-services.json in my FirebaseOptions so my main looks like this:

```
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: 'AIzaSyAz2kNBgLq_vJw2WjzSkdt2HwVP1k814TI',
        appId: '1:288911819468:android:ba34dab02e6268dc683869',
        messagingSenderId: '288911812458',
        projectId: 'fir-series-e6357',
        storageBucket: 'fir-series-e6357.appspot.com'
    )
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
```