# flutter web firebase no default bucket

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I'm trying to upload file to firebase storage and I got this  Error: [firebase_storage/no-bucket] No default storage bucket could be found. Ensure you have correctly followed the Getting Started guide.
i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70763172/flutter-firebase-storage-not-woriking-no-default-bucket)  and i have the same error
this is my main :

```
Future main()  async {
  runApp(StartPoint());
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: "myapp",
    options: kIsWeb || Platform.isAndroid ? FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: "api_key",
      appId: "appID",
      messagingSenderId: "messaging",
      projectId: "proID",
      storageBucket: "myapp.appspot.com",
    ):null,
  );
}
```